# Is renaming an SQL constraint a dangerous change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rename

We are thinking about renaming different constraints on our production database.
Is this a dangerous breaking change and if so, to which extent, or can we update blindly? I guess I'm trying to figure out what's the worst case scenario here.

As far as I know, the only place where the name of the constraints could be used are:

- scripts that explicitly manipulate those constraints
- stored procedures, but that seems far-fetched

Our database is accessed via EF 6.1 and classic asp.

Comment: Well, there is one way to find out pretty quick....  Is EF making the constraints by doing code first or are you guys managing the db end?

Comment: I rename constraints all the time... exactly so that scripts can explicitly manipulate them, because the system-generated defaults are unusable for this purpose. If they already *have* meaningful names, you need to take care for exactly that reason.

Comment: Seems very unlikely to be dangerous to me.  It's very unlikely that anyone wrote code that uses your constraint name to do anything.

Comment: Assuming your constraints here are things like foreign keys or check constraints, then it sounds ok, but if it's about primary keys or unique indexes, someone might use them in index hints. That of course depends a lot about your environment.

Comment: As @JeroenMostert mentioned, if they are currently meaningful names, it seems like someone had an intention of relying on those. I also take the time to ensure check constraints and such have a specific pattern of meaningful names. Those names potentially get parsed downstream in the event a not so well caught error is thrown. Might be something to look into if anyone has error handling built around the names.